# Why is the normal distribution family in GLMs homoscedastic?

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, variance, intuition

As the question asks, what allows us to assume that the normal distribution family exhibits homoscedasticity?

Comment: It does so purely by definition.  Are you therefore asking what about *some particular application scenario* permits this assumption?  Are you asking how to check it in practice?

Comment: My guess was that he had problems understanding the definitions.

Comment: Because the [variance-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_function#Generalized_linear_model) (as defined for GLMs) is constant in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal family of distributions for a regression model $Y_i \sim \text{N}(\mu_i=x_i^T \beta,\sigma^2)$.  This means that we assumes that our random variable $Y_i$ have some normal distribution with some unknown mean $\mu_i=x_i^T \beta$ and unknown variance $\sigma^2$.  This says that, whatever is the value of the predictor variables $x_i$, the variance of the observation is the same. That is homoskedasticity!

We could have written the model in some other way, such as (lets say with one predictor variable $z$) the distribution is $Y_i \sim \text{N}(\mu_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 z,\exp(\gamma z))$, where the variance is some function of the predictor $z$, depending on parameters to be estimated.  Such a model would be heteroskedastic, but is not a part of the usual glm framework.  In `R` such models can be estimated with the `gamlss` package (and certainly others).

```
 EDIT
```

Answer to extra question in comment:  Look at the binomial family. For the normal family, we have two independent parameters, so we can specify mean and variance separately.  Not so for the binomial model! If $Y \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$, where $n$ is not considered usually a parameter, since it is defined by the data, we have only one parameter $p$. Then we can calculate that the expectation is $\mu=n p$ and the variance is $\sigma^2= n p (1-p)$. Note that **we can write the variance as a function of the expectation**: $\sigma^2 = \mu (1-\frac{\mu}{n})$. So, in say, logistic regression, when we estimate in some way the expectation as a function of covariables, that will determine automatically the variance as a function of covariables.  There is no freedom in estimating the variance as soon as we have estimated the mean, is it already determined.
 The same happens for the Poisson family.

Comment: Why is it that in GLMs, the normal family displays homoscedasticity while other members of the exponential family do not?